# What will be the result of atoi(argv[1])?

Tags: c++

I just want to know what these lines actually do.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

And especially this one:

```
int n = atoi (argv[1]);
```

I read this in a book but I cannot understand these lines.

Comment: i tried to run this program but get error on this line. So that;s why i wanted to know its result.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This is the #2 result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This converts the first command-line argument to an integer. For example, if you call your program like this

```
./a.out 123
```

then `n` will be `123`.

Note that before accessing `argv[1]` one must check that `argc` is greater than `1`, i.e. check that at least one argument has been passed to your program on a command line.

Comment: @user1815004 When you compile your program under UNIX, the name of your executable is usually `a.out`. The `./` part is there because the current directory is not commonly placed on the default execution path (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

argc is the count of argument. argv is short for argument variable. It will contain all arguments passed on the command line. argv[1] contains the first argument so atoi(argv[1]) will convert the first argument to an int

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The first parameter to main, argc, is the number of command line arguments. For example, if the user enters:

`./a.out 5 6 7`

`argc` will be `4` **(a.out counts as one of the command line arguments, and 5, 6, and 7 as three more).**

`argv` is an array of strings):

```
        -----
argv[0]:| *-|"./a.out"
        -----
argv[1]:| *-| "5"
        -----
argv[2]:| *-| "6"
        -----
argv[3]:| *-| "7"
        -----
argv[4]:| *-| "\0"
        -----
```

`atoi()` functionconverts string data type to int data type.
since commandline arguments `(argv[])` can only take `strings`, you need to convert that string`into`arithmetic numbers`in order to use it as such. The`atoi` (alphabetical to integer) does that for you where it takes in any **string and converts the numbers inside the string into arithmetic numbers.**